# how to rewrite a single URL to add .html in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I ported an old static HTML site to wordpress. All posts and pages now have permalinks /%postname%/

I need a single post URL to include the .html extension (it needs to match the original canonical URL which included the .html)

EXAMPLE:

www.domain.com/thispageonly/

-TO-

www.domain.com/thispageonly.html

This is needed for a single post only nothing more.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use 301 redirect for this (SEO reasons):

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /thispageonly /thispageonly.html
```

Comment: Thanks edvinas - I was thinking it would be that easy but that does not work. Tried it in the WP .htaccess as well as the root level .htaccess

Comment: Thanks again! but a redirect won't work I need a rewrite that works with wordpress.

Comment: 301 redirect error like page method ...  But need,  How to add .html end of all post/page url in wordpress ...